# Whats up with the URL's fragment for generic methods?

Tags: java, javadoc, nested-generics

I'm using *IntelliJ IDEA* and have it set up to open the JavaDoc for any type or member in my browser. Now it seems that IntelliJ IDEA can't guess the full URL for methods that have a generic type as parameter, when I try to to open the documentation for the method `java.lang.Object.isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)` it asks which of these two URLs should be opened:

- `file:///[...]/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class<?>)`
- `file:///[...]/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)`

Are these two competing standards for encoding the type of a method with generic parameters? Can I assume that only one will be used in the future (presumably the first)?

For an added bonus: Is there a way to set up IntelliJ IDEA to automatically chose one of these forms by defaults?

Comment: Wouldn't you have a JDK 1.4 lying somewhere? The prototype of Java 5+ is the first one without a doubt. How do you use it?

Comment: I've only set up JDK 1.6 and never used or installed anything below that. It also happens for non-JDK libraries. I'm using the _View > External Documentation_ action from the main menu.